# Jumbotron background image is not synchronous with HTML background image

Tags: html, css, background

I want to cover my page with a background image and I am using a jumbotron which covers all components of page but its size is not cover all page. So, I also attached a background image to .html in my css file.

```
    .jumbotron {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Now, image look like a broken mirror. How can I made it look like a single image? Or what is the logical way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply background image on body tag.

```
body {
      width:100%;
      background-image: url('background.jpg');
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: But then background is done but jumbotron background is not set to image, seems white.

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet so I can check

Comment: Sorry, this worked when I changed opacity of jumbotron